# Better alternative to link_to :back for Cancel buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my web application I have a form that is accessible from multiple screens. I'd like the Cancel button in the form to lead back to the previous page. The `link_to 'Cancel', :back` solution doesn't work if form is submitted before the Cancel button is pressed. In such case it simple refreshes the page, which is an expected behavior.

What is a path-independent alternative that ensures that the Cancel button always leads to the screen that the form was opened from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.referer` as a 'Cancel' button. But I'm not sure how it will handle the submit.

Another solution would be to store the page where the user came from in a `session`, and then redirect them back there

Comment: I believe referrer is updated to the current page after submit. Storing in session potential solution. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed a few reusable forms by splitting them into a partial and then passing the URLs to the partial. This way the html is fully reusable. Looks not as pretty but it's clear what it does